# Assumptions in the Tavis-Cummings Model

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-optics

Consider identical two-level atoms interacting with single mode of light.  The interaction Hamiltonian can be written as

$$H^{1}=\hbar \sum_{j=1}^{N} \left(g_{j}\hat{S}_{+}^{(j)} \hat{a} + \mathrm{h.c.}\right)$$

The $g_{j}$ for different $j$ are different, so finding eigenvalues/eigenvectors for the above Hamiltonian is very difficult, but we can approximate $g_{j}$ as a number independent of $j$ when we have the following assumptions:

1. When the distance between the Rydberg atoms are very smaller compared to wavelength.
2. When the atoms are placed at the anti-nodes of the cavity.

These statements are from the book *Quantum Optics* by R.S. Agarwal.

I can't understand how these two statements leads to constant $g$ for all atoms.  Can someone give physical arguments/explanation why these above statements leads to constant $g$ from the atomic physics point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The value $g_j$ encodes the coupling of the $j$-th atom to the cavity mode. This coupling has an amplitude and phase which should be taken into account. Although I don't know the context in this book (for example, what is the relevance of these atoms being in Rydberg state?), the two conditions you gave can reasonably enforce that both the amplitudes and phases of $g_j$ are uniform.

The amplitude is proportional to the strength of the electric field at the position of the atom. In a standing wave mode, the electric field oscillates in space. If atoms are randomly distributed, then they will couple to different magnitudes of the electric field. However, if atoms all sit at antinodes (where the electric field is maximal), then they are locally insensitive to fluctuations since the slope is flat. To first order, then, the amplitudes of $g_j$ should be uniform if atoms are all sitting at cavity antinodes.

The phases of the coupling constants denote if the atoms will `resonate' in phase or out of phase with one another. The relative phase is determined by the distance between the atoms, compared to the wavelength $\lambda$ of the electromagnetic field. If two atoms are $\lambda$ apart, and they both radiate a field, then the fields will constructively interfere. If the atoms are $\lambda/2$ apart, the fields will destructively interfere. This relative phase is captured by $e^{2\pi i (\Delta x / \lambda)}$, where $\Delta x$ is the distance between atoms. With many atoms, it makes more sense to write down the coupling term for each atom with the position-dependent phase $e^{2\pi i (x_j / \lambda)}$.

If the wavelength $\lambda$ is much larger than the spatial extent of the system of atoms, then $|x_j| \ll \lambda$, so each position-dependent phase is approximately the same. This might be why Rydberg atoms were invoked in the question -- because they can be coupled to large-wavelength microwave fields, rather than short-wavelength optical fields.